# Prove that for every natural number $n$, there exists a natural number $m$ such that $\frac{1}{m}-\frac{1}{m+1} < \frac{1}{n}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, proof-writing

I am not sure how to proceed with my proof. I can easily explain in words why this is so (just by maximizing the values of the LHS and RHS then noting the left will always decrease faster than the RHS due to denominator getting smaller), but I do not think this is mathematically valid and doesn't necessarily *prove* anything.

This is how I did it.

$\frac{1}{m} - \frac{1}{m+1} < \frac{1}{n}$

$=\frac{1}{m(m+1)} < \frac{1}{n}$

Now, I am sadly stuck and have no way to proceed. I am thinking to expand this inequality like $\frac{1}{m(m+1)}  < \text{something} < \frac{1}{n}$

or

$\text{something}  < \frac{1}{m(m+1)}  < \frac{1}{n}$, but I am not sure how to go about this or if this is even the right approach.

Comment: The partial fraction recombination is appropriate, but there are no limits listed for $n$ so it is always possible to choose $n$ to make the inequality fail.  Are there more conditions than you have listed?

Comment: That inequality does *not* hold for all $m, n$.

Comment: @abiessu sorry, updated the title.

Comment: @MartinR apologies, updated the title.

Comment: Now you can choose (for example) $m=n$.

Comment: Based on the new title, let $m=n$.  Then the inequality holds.

Comment: Is the problem supposed to be "for every natural number $n$, there is an integer $m$ ..."?

Comment: Let $m=n$ then the problem is solved

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have $\frac{1}{m(m+1)} < \frac{1}{n}$, which is equivalent to
$m(m+1) > n$. Surely you can find a value of $m$ that will make this true.

Answer (score 0):

Even more directly, if $m=n$, then $\frac 1m - \frac {1}{m+1} = \frac 1n - \frac{1}{n+1} \lt \frac 1n$ because $\frac {1}{n+1} \gt 0$.